# string resource identifier not found

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

I'm facing a strange problem on my android project. I'm write some strings inside strings.xml file, and i'll retrieve it from my code with

```
context.getString(R.string.resource_id);
```

and from xml

```
android:text="@string/resource_id"
```

I've addedd several strings, but the last i'm adding give me problems. The problem is that string resource id is not found (it seems that eclipse don't generate the reference inside R file).
I've already try different solutions like:

clean project
fix project proprieties
restart ide
and all combinations of this actions, but nothing happen. I'm stuck and frustrated about this problem. How can i solve?

Comment: can you post the strings.xml file?

Comment: there's no error inside strings file

Comment: does the string have special characters like '? these need escaping \'

Comment: as you say `but the last i'm adding give me problems`, for a temporary fix add a dummy string at the end as fix until you figure out this :-/

Answer (score 0):

Usually I got this problem when I had a bad xml reference in some layout or menu. Try to find it then rebuild your project and Eclipse will regenerate the correct R file